# Unit testing using Pex

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pex

I want to unit test following code using Pex:

```
    private string GetOriginalFieldName(string p)
    {
        var strMapField = string.Empty;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gdFields.Rows)
        {
            var strOriginal = row.Cells[0].Text;
            var txt = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].FindControl("txt");
            switch (string.Compare(p, strOriginal, true))
            {
                case 0:
                    if (txt.Text != null) return txt.Text;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (string.Compare(p, strOriginal + ":", true) == 0)
                    {
                        if (txt.Text != null) return txt.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strMapField = p;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return strMapField;
    }
```

This function search text from gridview rows and replace input string with mapfield of gridview.

How to unit test using Pex?

Comment: This is not a good case for a unit test. You need to break out your business logic (`replace input string with mapfield of gridview`) from your presentation logic (`FindControl` and `GridView`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use PEX on this type of unit test since you have an instance of a GridView (`gdFields`) which needs to be instanciated for the test to work. In this case you may want to look at [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) which is an isolation framework which could allow you to create a fake instance of the GridView control.

Somehow you will need to create a fake GridView with fake textboxes and the such, in order for the code to run without a `NullReferenceException`.

Now I'm not experienced with Moles so I can't say 100% that you can create a fake GridView with it, but certainly have a look. PEX and Moles do work well together though.